# FFMPEG - No such filter: '' - Error initializing complex filters

Tags: ffmpeg

Please help me understanding error from code below:

```
ffmpeg -i video_9870.mp4 -i video_5178.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=977.58[V01];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart video_6179.mp4


[AVFilterGraph @ 0000005f6f004700] No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Regards,

Comment: Remove the last `;` in your `filter_complex`.

Comment: I am getting below error: Output with label 'video' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.   Script: ffmpeg -i video_9870.mp4 -i video_5178.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=
fade:duration=0.5:offset=977.58[V01];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A0
1]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart video_6179.mp4

Comment: This error is because you are not using the [video] pad in your filter graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing semi-colon at the end of the filtergraph.

The `-map` args will give you an error since no such pads are labelled inside the filtergraph. You can just remove them altogether.

`ffmpeg -i video_9870.mp4 -i video_5178.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=977.58;[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri" -movflags +faststart video_6179.mp4`